# How to use i18n-webpack-plugin along with other loaders?

Tags: webpack, internationalization

I'm using `file-loader` to emit image files and `html-loader` to load html templates into js code. Everything had been fine until our team decided to introduce internationalization. I checked the `i18n-webpack-plugin` and it seems the very thing I need.

I successfully configured the webpack and it builds two versions of static files in two different paths, `dist/lang1` and `dist/lang2` respectively. Since `i18n-webpack-plugin` requires exporting [multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations), all the image files are emitted twice by the `file-loader` into these two paths. I modified my configuration file a little bit and managed to emit the image files into `dist`.

So far, the `dist` directory looks exactly how I want it to:

```
dist/
   |---lang1/
   |     |
   |     '-----app.hash1.js  // references image files correctly
   |     |
   |     '-----index.html // loads app.hash1.js in <script> tag
   |---lang2/
   |     |
   |     '-----app.hash2.js // references image files correctly
   |     |
   |     '-----index.html // loads app.hash2.js in <script> tag
   |
   |--- image1-hash.jpg
   |
   |--- image2-hash.jpg
   |
   ·--- image3-hash.jpg
```

I'm not happy about the process generates this result:

```
webpack runs for the `lang1` configuration 
>>>>> loads files according to dependency, using corresponding loaders
>>>>>>>>>>>>> if it contains localization function ( __() by default ), 
              replaces it with lang1 translation
>>>>>>>>>>>>> if one file matches file-loader test, copys it into dist   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
webpack runs for the `lang2` configuration 
>>>>> loads files according to dependency, using corresponding loaders
>>>>>>>>>>>>> if it contains localization function ( __() by default ), 
              replaces it with lang2 translation
>>>>>>>>>>>>> if one file matches file-loader test, copys it into dist
```

Many jobs (like less compiling, image copying, js linting, etc.) are done twice (n times for n language supports) here and the build performance is terrible.

Is there a way to hack this?